# Django RF simplejwt returns only token, not user object

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have React app and a Redux store. I am working on an authentication now. My backend is on Django RF and for JWT auth I use a simplejwt lib. The thing is, that this lib has an "out of the box" view (/token) that returns a JWT token on success.

The problem is that I need to have a user object in my app upon successful authentication. So when the user logs in it returns a token only. But I need to redirect the user to their page if logged in.

I sure can override this /token view and return whatever object I want, but why is this implemented this way right now?

Comment: A token is returned so that the client (like your React app) can use it to make authenticated requests. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I need to have a user instance stored in a Redux store. I can probably use just a token and get the user instance from request.user further in the app but I need some user's info to render on the page like email, name so on. So I feel like returning it once upon successful login is the best solution here. I have posted how I implemented it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is no other way that to override validate() method in serializers.py like this:

```
class UserTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        data = {
            'token': super().validate(attrs),
            'id': self.user.id,
            'email': self.user.email,
            'name': self.user.name,
        }
        return data
```